# Bringing activity infront of the callscreen

Tags: android

I've created an application which shows a dialog when phone receives a call from a number starts with particular string. To achieve that I created a transparent activity and created a dialog like UI. It works fine on the emulator because emulator shows stock caller UI. But for the real devices it has a full screen UI for the caller screen which hides my transparent activity. Is it possible to bring that activity in front of the caller screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by getting request from user to overlay on system UI and my transparent activity is overlaying on it